# How to add picture in php interbase or firebird server using php

Tags: php

We have asoftware engineering project i need to put picture in the database using blob of php interbase using firebird server. Could someone give me some reerences to do it. Or some example?
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a method call insertBlob or name it anything you want.
then open the file as binary, 'rb' means read binary so you can save it to your database as a blob type.

```
public function insertBlob($filePath,$mime){
$blob = fopen($filePath,'rb');

$sql = "INSERT INTO files(mime,data) VALUES(:mime,:data)";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':mime',$mime);
$stmt->bindParam(':data',$blob,PDO::PARAM_LOB);

return $stmt->execute();
```

}

now you can do somethiling like this..

```
insertBlob('C:/picture1.png','image/png');
```